# Importing Markdown file into React component in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

**In Gatsby, how can I display the contents of a markdown file within a React component?**

I am using the official [gatsby-starter-blog](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/) starter which comes with markdown support. It works great for the blog posts that are already set up.

However, I now added a new About page. And on that page, rather than writing all of the content in jsx, I would like to write some of the content in a separate markdown file that I can import into the React component for my About page.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Folder structure:

```
content
- pages
-- about-content.md
src
- pages
-- about-page.js
```

PS: I do not want my md file turned into its own page. I want to import it into a React component. And I want that component to be the page.

Comment: any source (json/md/file/wp) is available by query ... usually iterating on source you're creating page using template (page) component... but you don't have to create page from every source ... and you can use query in page component to access other source (like sitemetadata) - use `/__graphql` to find query with data (from md) you need

Comment: @xadm do you need any other plugins / modules for __graphql to find / make available the MD files you might have in any folder on your site?

Comment: did you read https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/ ?

Answer (score 2):

In `gatsby-starter-blog` this is the [code snippet](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/master/src/templates/blog-post.js#L40) that turns the markdown text into a blog page:

```
<section dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
```

You take the GraphQL query and the code snippet from above and put it into the `about-page.js` component:

```
const About = (props) => {
  const { data: { legal: { edges } } } = props;
  const { node: { childMarkdownRemark: { frontmatter, html } } } = edges[0];

  return (
    <Layout>

        // display other React components

        <section dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} /> // display markdown

        // display other React comonents

    </Layout>
  );
}

export const query = graphql`
{
  legal: allFile(
    filter: {
      internal: {
        mediaType: {eq: "text/markdown"}}, 
      name: {eq: "about-content"}
    edges {
      node {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
export default About;
```

Note that Gatsby implicitly builds urls out of your file names inside the `pages` folder. So the url would be `localhost:8000/about-page/`.